# How to edit css of "Document Library Previewer" web part on Sharepoint online/designer?

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Info/Problem.

- Using Sharepoint online with a dark/black theme.
- On the homepage, I am using the document library previewer web part.
- The font for URL's/Hyperlinks is defaulting to black so they aren't visible on the black background.
- Attempting to change the font color of these URL's using CSS.

What I've tried

- I've used the Dev Tools in Chrome to locate and change the CSS to make the font color white. This works, but the changes don't save after I refresh the page.
- Downloaded and Installed Sharepoint Designer and copied the style element to a txt file stored in the style library. I'm not sure how or where to insert this file in Sharepoint designer to apply to to my site

The ideal solution would be editing the CSS for the homepage and then saving it permanently. I feel like I've gotten most of the way there, I just can't figure out how to save/apply my changes.

If it isn't already obvious, I'm not much of a developer so I'm a bit out of my depth here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can customize the css of existing webpart using designer. You have to create your own previewer using spfx. there are some [webparts](https://github.com/OlivierCC/spfx-40-fantastics) you can checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! On a semi-related note, do you know if it's possible to persist changes to a webpart using Chrome's dev tools? I've been able to make the change I want, I just can't get it saved

Comment: Using chrome dev tools only allows you to edit on you local machine, it cannot save the changes to the server code, which can only be done through deplyment. That means you need to have access to source code so that you can change and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the CSS style code into Script Editor web part in the home page?

If you use modern page, check the solution below.

[react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)